# Kali Linux on Raspberry Pi4 with touchscreen LCD display is not booting with GUI

Tags: linux, lcd, kali

I have successfully installed latest kali Linux image for rpi4 available on offensive security website. Its 2020.1. I have also configured the display with `kalipi-tft-config` command but on reboot, no GUI of kali Linux is shown only a terminal like safe mode is seen. I am not getting any solution for this on the internet. Please suggest me any solution that can fix the problem.

Also note that:- **I have waveshare 3.5inch lcd tft display version "A"**.

**If someone knows the solution please reply.**

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Kali Linux before, but my guess from looking at the home page is that you may not have a desktop environment installed.

I would also try using another display just to see if that is the problem.

Comment: if I user windows remote desktop i.e. xrdp or rdp I can see the desktop with proper gui

Comment: I don't know then. Perhaps try backing up and resinstalling,

Comment: Still nothing happens. I have tried it several times

Comment: any answers for this issue?